# Deriving device connection string from the environment

Tags: azure-iot-edge

`IoT` modules can be created from the environment using :

```
 ModuleClient.CreateFromEnvironmentAsync(settings)
```

However, there does not seem to be an equivalent method for devices. For now, I am setting the device connection string in the program to test it out, but is there a better way to read teh connection string from `iotedge/config.yaml` for all the edge devices deployed out there?

Methods to do so for .NET and python would be appreciated.

Comment: In other words, I'm looking to use something like the following. However, not sure what's the recommended way to set environment directly from config.yaml file.. DeviceConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("IOTHUB_DEVICE_CONN_STRING");

Answer (score 0):

You can use a yaml parse library to deserialize the document, such as YamlDotNet. In fact, you can refer to [YamlDocument](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/blob/52ef77db24126bf473265fc09c53d35290a2dd6b/smoke/IotEdgeQuickstart/details/YamlDocument.cs) in iot edge. But in the class, it does not provide a method to get the key value. Please refer to following code.

```
public class YamlDocument
{
    readonly Dictionary<object, object> root;

    public YamlDocument(string input)
    {
        var reader = new StringReader(input);
        var deserializer = new Deserializer();
        this.root = (Dictionary<object, object>)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    public object GetKeyValue(string key)
    {
        if(this.root.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return this.root[key];
        }

        foreach(var item in this.root)
        {
            var subItem = item.Value as Dictionary<object, object>;
            if(subItem != null && subItem.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return subItem[key];
            }
        }

        return null;            
    }
}
```

And then you can get the device connection string from the config.yaml. If you use python, you can import yaml library to analysis the file.

```
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\ProgramData\iotedge\config.yaml");
        var yamlString = sr.ReadToEnd();

        var yamlDoc = new YamlDocument(yamlString);
        var connectionString = yamlDoc.GetKeyValue("device_connection_string");
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", connectionString);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Michael Xu.  I tried the solution, which looks like it should work. But the problem now is that /etc/iotedge/config.yaml is not readable by the container. The exact error message is below...

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Could not find a part of the path '/etc/iotedge/config.yaml'.) ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/etc/iotedge/config.yaml'.
   at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
..

Comment: Update: Your code above did work as long as I add the config file tot he container during the build. Now, if we are manually running docker, one can use the volume option (-v /etc/iotconfig:<dst>) to copy the config file over to the container. However, I don't see a way to do that using Dockerfile and in a normal scaled deployment. Any ideas? Thanks for the code snippet, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

To get the config file from the host, add the following to the docker deployment file. Note that the source file is config1.yaml which is the same as config.yaml except that it has read permissions for everyone not just root.

"createOptions": "{\"HostConfig\":{\"Binds\":[\"/etc/iotedge/config1.yaml:/app/copiedConfig.yaml\"]}}"

With the above line in place, the copiedConfig.yaml file can be used in the container, along with @Michael Xu's parsing code to derive teh connection string.

Long term, one may want to use the device provisioning service anyway but hope this helps for folks using device conenction strings for whatever reason..

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. In you scenario, I think using `env` to set the connection string as an environment is another option. When you create an IoT Edge solution, you can `.env` file in the solution project. This file  lists your environment variables. And then use python or .Net to get the value.

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT, Since I'd want the device string to be uniquely determined for each device, how can I set it in the env? The only way seemed to be parsing the config file.

Comment: The Azure IoT Edge Dev Tool greatly simplifies Azure IoT Edge development down to simple commands driven by Environment Variables.More detailed information [here](https://github.com/Azure/iotedgedev).

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelXu-MSFT. Looks very useful. I'll try it. I still don't see how env can be used to solve my problem (I do need it to be startup option since the connection string is different for each edge device), but I'll probably see it when I try. Thanks for your help..